# Can't view Ubuntu Server (VM) in browser, I can connect with SSH

Tags: server, ssh, apache2, php

I can't seem to be able to access my php files in a browser from my external ip.

I have a Ubuntu Server VM set up on my Windows desktop. I also have a Windows laptop that I use (99% of the time, it's outside the network). I have OpenSSH on the server. The server has a bridged adapter setup (Promiscuous Mode: Deny). For ease, lets say the internal ip of the server is `1.1.1.1` (listening on port `2222`) and the exernal ip of my home network is `2.2.2.2`.

I set up port forwarding so that when I access `2.2.2.2:2222`, I forward to the interal ip of `1.1.1.1:2222`. This allows me to SSH into the server VM from both inside and outside the network.

This is a test server for an app, so I need to make php calls to execute queries on databases (MySQL) and I'd like to be able to view the JSON results to make sure everything is working. On my desktop, I can access the php files in my browser by connecting to `1.1.1.1/helloworld.php` (internal ip). I cannot access the php files from my browser with my external ip address. I get the same results:

Desktop (internal):

- `2.2.2.2:2222/helloworld.php` (hopefully using port forwarding) gives me a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error
- `2.2.2.2/helloworld.php` (this is router stuff, I have an Asus running AsusWRT) Settings have been updated. Web page will now refresh.
  Changes have been made to the IP address or port number. You will now be disconnected from RT-N66U.
  To access the settings of RT-N66U, reconnect to the wireless network and use the updated IP address and port number.

Laptop (external):

- `2.2.2.2:2222/helloworld.php` (hopefully using port forwarding) gives me a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error
- `2.2.2.2/helloworld.php` (just connect me to something...) gives me a ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error

I'd like to be able to use this test server from any browser, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your configuration lacks a port 80 forwarding from your router to 1.1.1.1:80.

Comment: Yahtzee. Is there a way to do this without using 2 different port forwards? I only ask because most routers have a limit (I'm not close to reaching mine, but I could see it happening when using VM servers).

Comment: You can use SSH as a proxy SOCKS, but it will only works for ssh authentified users (usable for you but not if you need to share a link to your script)